# dictionary TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, types

I have this code:

```
def function_factory(x,y,o):
    d = {'+':x+y,'-':x-y,'*':x*y,'/':x/y,'%':x%y}
    for k,v in d.items():
        if o == k:
            return v
```

So if I input `print(function_factory(3,4,'*'))` then what I would expect to get is `12` but instead I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(function_factory(2,3,'+')(), 5)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I tried a different way of doing it but I still get this error. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: it seems that the function intedns to tell you what type op operation were used not the evaluation of the operator...

Comment: You aren't inputting `function_factory(...)` you're inputting `function_factory(...)()` which is calling the return value of that

Comment: Can try this: return str(<variable>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should not call your function result and insted assert the it: `function_factory(2,3,'+')` and not `function_factory(2,3,'+')()` just as @Sayse said in comments

second, your function will tell you what is the operation to get the result..  not the result of a operation:

if this is your intention, you should use it like this:

```
function_factory(2,5,10)
>>> '*'

function_factory(2,5,7)
>>> '+'

function_factory(2,5,-3)
>>> '-'

function_factory(2,5,2/5)
>>> '/'
```

in case you want to make it work as you expect,and not as i showed you how it is already working, you should change your function:

```
def function_factory(x,y,o):
    d = {'+':x+y,'-':x-y,'*':x*y,'/':x/y,'%':x%y}
    return d[o]
```

and then the result would be :

```
function_factory(3,4,'*')
>>> 12
```

Comment: Your own "fix" doesn't explain your first initial explanation, if `o` was `10` then it'd return a `KeyError` not the operator that the op inputs (which is not what they are trying to achieve anyway)